# How to Access google sheets API using Service account keys .p12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to access public google sheets using google APIs.

Authentication is service accounts, I have .p12/.json file with me. How to proceed with this

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution,

Create a script in **google scripts** and access sheet through script. And publish script as API.

Done!!